# Can't run Flutter project on Android Studio 4.1. No valid code signing certificates were found

Tags: python, macos, android-studio, flutter, virtualbox

VirtualBox 6.1

Create virtual machine **MacOS 10.15 Catalina**

Install Android Studio 4.1

Install Flutter  plugin

Install XCode

On virtual machine start Android Studio and success run my Flutter project on connected Android device.

On Android device show dialog for is I trusted this computer.

I selected "**TRUST**".

Nice.

Now I connect iPhone on virtual machine and try to run my Flutter project in Android Studio.

On iPhone device show dialog for is I trusted this computer.

I selected "**TRUST**"

But I get error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Alex's iPhone in debug mode...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
No valid code signing certificates were found
You can connect to your Apple Developer account by signing in with your Apple ID
in Xcode and create an iOS Development Certificate as well as a Provisioning 
Profile for your project by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected. 
     - For Xcode 10, look under General > Signing > Team.
     - For Xcode 11 and newer, look under Signing & Capabilities > Team.
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again
  5- Trust your newly created Development Certificate on your iOS device
     via Settings > General > Device Management > [your new certificate] > Trust
For more information, please visit:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/
  AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html
Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Exception: No development certificates available to code sign app for device deployment
```

Comment: are your don't purchase apple developer? this exception is not development certificate, apple real device necessary  apple developer certificate

Comment: @rollcake Is it possible to start Flutter project on iphone emulator on virtualbox , macOS Catalina ?